# How do I re-use my account information on Kindle app?

Tags: kindle-for-android

I downloaded the Kindle app from the Play Store but I uninstalled it after trying it out because I went tested other ereaders as well. The problem is, when I decided to settle for the Kindle app. I downloaded it and there was no option to log in. Only an option to **Register**. Thus, when I "Registered" again with the same account information I used before, my device was dubbed "My Name's 2nd Android". I also lost my first @kindle.com email and it has now been appended with some numbers. Is there any way to get around this?

[image]

Comment: I think "Registering" is essentially akin to logging in, but it attempts to tie your device to your account using some kind of identifier so that Amazon can keep track of how many mobile devices you have accessing your account. You could try going into your Amazon settings (on their website) and removing all of your devices, then re-registering. You can do this from the "Your Account" page by clicking the "Your Apps and Devices" link (it's in the Digital Content section).

Comment: Yes, you "Register" the device as an authorized device for your Amazon account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get back your `@kindle` email address (assuming someone else hasn't acquired it in the meanwhile), browse to Amazon.com and navigate to Your Account > Manage Your Kindle > Manage Your Devices > Personal Documents Settings (this last link is rather less than obvious, below the panel showing a photo of a KF).  There is a link there to edit/change the KF's email address.  You can do this from any computer; it doesn't have be done on your KF.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, what I needed to do was instead, go to Your Account > Manage Your Kindle > Manage Your Devices and Deregister "My Name's Android" which I think I failed to do before uninstalling it before. Then clear the data on the Android app then open it up to setup again. Everything is now back to normal. Your post helped me get to that section of the website. :P